# How to order rows by conditions in other columns in r?

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, bioinformatics

I have a genetic dataset where I am looking to order samples/genes, grouping by those which are in a certain distance to each other in the genome.

So for example my dataset looks like:

```
#dt1
Gene    chromosome position      CP 
Gene1      1       70000200   1:70000200
Gene2      5       10000476   5:10000476
Gene3      1       70000201   1:70000201
Gene4      5       10000475   5:10000475
```

I also have an origin position dataset:

```
#dt2
chromosome   position  CP
    1        70005000  1:70005000
    5        10005000  5:10005000
```

I am trying to group genes in my 1st dataset if they are within +/- 500000 distance of any position in my second dt2 dataset and are on the same chromosome. I have an issue in my actual data where this might be true for a gene against multiple origin dt2 positions, so I'm also trying to sort to the one it is closest to.

Output aims to give ordered groups:

```
Gene   chromosome  position   Group 
Gene1      1       70000200    1
Gene3      1       70000201    1
Gene4      5       10000475    2
Gene2      5       10000476    2
```

Gene1 and Gene3 are within the 500000 of an origin dt2 position and all are on the same chromosome so grouped together and the same for Genes 4 and 2

Currently I am trying to do this with:

```
dt2[, c("low", "high") := .(position - 500000, position  + 500000)]

#find matches on chromosome, with position between low&high
dt1[ dt2, match := i.CP,
     on = .(chromosome, position > low, position < high ) ]

#outputs:
    Gene chromosome position    CP        match
1   Gene1   1   70000200    1:70000200  1:70005000
2   Gene2   5   10000476    5:10000476  5:10005000
3   Gene3   1   70000201    1:70000201  1:70005000
4   Gene4   5   10000475    5:10000475  5:10005000
```

I am having problems with this on 2 levels with seemingly not getting this output for the match column on my actual data, so I am wondering if there are other ways to code this that I can try. I am also struggling to convert the match column into grouping matches and identifying the groups as I want in my expected output, I have a biology background so I'm unsure how to change this - any help would be appreciated.

Input data:

```
#dt1:
structure(list(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4"), 
    chromosome = c(1L, 5L, 1L, 5L), position = c(70000200L, 10000476L, 
    70000201L, 10000475L), CP = c("1:70000200", "5:10000476", 
    "1:70000201", "5:10000475"), match = c("1:70005000", "5:10005000", 
    "1:70005000", "5:10005000")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

#dt2:
structure(list(chromosome = c(1L, 5L), position = c(70005000L, 
10005000L), CP = c("1:70005000", "5:10005000"), low = c(69505000, 
9505000), high = c(70505000, 10505000)), row.names = c(NA, -2L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 7):

There are packages geared for doing this in Bioconductor. So one thing you can use is `distanceToNearest()` from `GenomicRanges` . First we convert them to GRanges objects:

```
library(GenomicRanges)
gr1=makeGRangesFromDataFrame(dt1,seqnames.field="chromosome",start.field="position",end.field="position")
values(gr1) = dt1[,c("Gene","CP")]
```

Give a group for dt2:

```
dt2$Group = 1:nrow(dt2)
gr2=makeGRangesFromDataFrame(dt2,seqnames.field="chromosome",start.field="position",end.field="position")
```

This step will match every row in gr1 (dt1 GRanges) to its nearest Range in gr2 (dt2):

```
matches = distanceToNearest(gr1,gr2)
Hits object with 4 hits and 1 metadata column:
      queryHits subjectHits |  distance
      <integer>   <integer> | <integer>
  [1]         1           1 |      4799
  [2]         2           2 |      4523
  [3]         3           1 |      4798
  [4]         4           2 |      4524
  -------
  queryLength: 4 / subjectLength: 2
```

We assign this result back:

```
dt1$group = NA
dt1$group[queryHits(matches)] = dt2$Group[subjectHits(matches)]
dt1$distance = NA
dt1$distance[queryHits(matches)] = values(matches)$distance[subjectHits(matches)]
dt1

    Gene chromosome position         CP      match group distance
1: Gene1          1 70000200 1:70000200 1:70005000     1     4799
2: Gene2          5 10000476 5:10000476 5:10005000     2     4523
3: Gene3          1 70000201 1:70000201 1:70005000     1     4799
4: Gene4          5 10000475 5:10000475 5:10005000     2     4523
```

Now you can filter away those that are > 500000

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for the idiomatic way of performing a non-equi join and then update by reference, i.e.

```
dt2[, c("rn", "low", "high") := .(.I, position - 500000L, position  + 500000L)]
#note that you perform the non-equi join first, and then 
#extract the result column before `:=`, which updates by reference
dt1[, Group := dt2[.SD, on=.(chromosome, low<position, high>position), rn]]
dt1
```

---

edit regarding multiple matches. In this case you will require a left join:

```
dt2[, group := .I][dt1, on=.(chromosome, low<position, high>position)]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I've tried it and it gives an error ```Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 26020579 rows; more than 169740 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values ``` I try adding ```allow.cartesian=TRUE``` but this also gives an error - is there a way for me to set the code to remove duplicates?

Comment: There are a lot of overlaps. That is each row of dt1 is joined to multiple rows of dt2. In such cases, which row would you choose?

Comment: I think I need the rows in dt1 to attach to each of the multiple rows it joins to in dt2 - would this be by applying ```rep()```?

Comment: @DN1, in this case you will require a left join then. I have added that to the answer

Comment: Thank you for this,  the new code runs with adding ```allow.cartesian=TRUE``` but is there a way for me to produce a group column for this too?

Comment: you mean rows from dt1 that have the same row from dt2 are in the same grp? added something in the edit

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants

- to group genes in `dt1` if they are within +/- 500000 distance of any position in `dt2` and are on the same chromosome.
- In case, a gene matches  multiple origin `dt2` positions, the closest one is to be selected.

So, a *rolling join to nearest* with subsequent filtering might be the answer.

```
library(data.table)
dt2[, Group := .I][
  dt1, on = .(chromosome, position), roll = "nearest",
  .(Gene, chromosome, position, CP = i.CP, 
    Group = fifelse(abs(x.position - i.position) <= 500000L, Group, NA_integer_))][
      order(Group, CP)]
```

> ```
>      Gene chromosome position         CP Group
> 1:  Gene1          1 70000200 1:70000200     1
> 2:  Gene3          1 70000201 1:70000201     1
> 3: Gene12          1 70005199 1:70005199     1
> 4: Gene13          1 70005900 1:70005900     2
> 5:  Gene4          5 10000475 5:10000475     3
> 6:  Gene2          5 10000476 5:10000476     3
> 7: Gene11          1 80000200 1:80000200    NA
> ```

Please, note that expanded datasets are used here in order to check if the approach is working for different use cases.

There is one gene, `Gene11`, in the expanded dataset which has been assigned to no group, i.e., `Group == NA`, because it has no matching position in `dt2` *within the distance threshold* of +/- 500000.

The approach is similar to [StupidWolf's `GenomicRanges` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62685108/3817004) but uses only `data.table` functionality.

#### Data

Both datasets have been expanded in order to cover different uses cases:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- fread("Gene    chromosome position      CP 
Gene1      1       70000200   1:70000200
Gene2      5       10000476   5:10000476
Gene3      1       70000201   1:70000201
Gene4      5       10000475   5:10000475
Gene11     1       80000200   1:80000200
Gene12     1       70005199   1:70005199
Gene13     1       70005900   1:70005900")
dt2 <- fread("chromosome   position  CP
    1        70005000  1:70005000
    1        70006000  1:70006000
    5        10005000  5:10005000")
```